# Github network graph not displaying correctly

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to follow a git branching strategy like the one in the image below:

[image: git branching strategy]

However, when I branch from `develop` into `release`, and then merge the `release` branch back into `develop` and `master`, the network graph on Github displays the following:

[image: Github network graph]

This makes it looks as if `develop` was branched from `release`, and not vice versa as it should be (especially once the release branch is deleted and its name no longer appears).

I followed the steps from [this tutorial](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) exactly:

1. `git checkout -b dev` (while on `master`)
2. make some changes and commit to `dev`
3. `git checkout -b release-1.0 dev`
4. make some changes and commit to `release-1.0`
5. `git checkout master`
6. `git merge --no-ff release-1.0`
7. `git checkout dev`
8. `git merge --no-ff release-1.0`

Is there any way to get the Github network graph to display correctly? (either by changing a setting in Github or changing the steps taken to branch and merge)

Comment: Git does not record origins of branches, and anything trying to display this kind of data has to guess. GitHub's guesser not only doesn't guess these cases well, it always seems rather broken to me (though its intent is not to display graphs just for *one* repo in the first place, but rather to track multiple repos linked via GitHub's "fork" operation). As far as I know (not very far, I'm only a light user of GitHub itself) there is no way to tweak this.

Comment: thanks @torek. in that case do you know a good command that can print something like this out on the command line?

Comment: Drawing good graphs is hard.  `git log --graph` does nearly the best possible with raw ASCII, IMO, but that's not very good. :-) The Pro Git book (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Graphical-Interfaces) links to https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Graphical_Interfaces but I have not tried most of these.

Comment: git tree track only the parent or parents of each commit so it can't tell that release branch were branched from dev at that point.
Only graphs that keeps the level of each branch on the same line may give you something that is parallel to the branching model graph, as long that you don't delete the release branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like GitHub is just not very good at displaying network graphs. For those who are curious, I just checked out [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/), and it seems to do a fantastic job at display network graphs. I also tried it out with a much more complicated repo I have and it is displaying things very nicely!

[image: GitKraken network graph]